# Do we indeed need mutex with attribute "PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED" which is opposite to "PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST"?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

I'm reading APUE Chapter 12(3rd edition) and it says: we can set either `PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED` or `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST` to the mutex.  But I don't think we need mutex with attribute `PTHREAD_MUTEX_STALLED`, mutex should always "robust" , so that we can be notified if the side which locked the mutex is dead. If mutex is "stalled", we will be suspending forever.

And I know that Windows' mutex is always be "robust" and we will be notified with error [`WAIT_ABANDONED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684266%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) if the side which locked the mutex is dead. So, in what kind of scenario, we have to use "stalled" mutex, not "robust" mutex?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: As stated your question is not clear and will probably be closed unless you clarify what you're asking.

Comment: I hope my edit hasn't modified the intended question. If so, please revert back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the following reasons why stalled mutex exists:

- If robust mutex is used then everytime you try to lock a mutex, you have to check for `EOWNERDEAD`. So it requires an additional check.
- If `EOWNERDEAD` is returned by `pthread_mutex_lock()` then you probably need to check all the state of shared objects that are relevant to that mutex has to checked and the mutex state has to reinstated by calling `pthread_mutex_lock()`.
- It's the default mutex attribute. Hence, no need for the application to call:`pthread_mutexattr_setrobust()`.
- Historical: early pthread implementations didn't have robust mutexes.

So all the above mentioned additional checks are only required if an application thinks a thread might die unexpectedly while holding a mutex, which is not how most threaded applications are designed. So it's a decision for an application to make if default behaviour (stalled) is sufficient or robust mutexes are needed.

Comment: Thanks. But on my CentOS6.3 x64, "robust" is not the default attribute.

Comment: That's what I said: stalled is default attribute.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand.